# Kivy Error: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize) when working with KivyMD

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I have been trying to find example code that will actually run and it has been difficult. I am trying to find code in kivy that can help me that will display a table then allow it to be changed by the user then exported to a text file. Here is the example code I found. In this code, I keep getting the error, object.**init**() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize).

```
from kivymd.uix.datatables import MDDataTable
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRectangleFlatButton


class Manager(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)


class SecondScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.table = MDDataTable(
            orientation = "lr-tb",
            size_hint=(0.9, 0.6),
            use_pagination=True,
            check=True,
            column_data=[
                ("No.", dp(30)),
                ("Column 1", dp(30)),
                ("Column 2", dp(30)),
                ("Column 3", dp(30)),
                ("Column 4", dp(30)),
                ("Column 5", dp(30)),
            ],
            row_data=[
                (f"{i + 1}", "2.23", "3.65", "44.1", "0.45", "62.5")
                for i in range(50)
            ],
        )

    def on_enter(self):
        self.table.open()


class FirstScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def change_screen(self):
        self.manager.current = "Second"


class TestApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.window_manager = Manager()
        self.first_screen = FirstScreen(name="First")
        self.sample_screen = SecondScreen(name="Second")
        self.window_manager.add_widget(self.first_screen)
        self.window_manager.add_widget(self.sample_screen)
        return self.window_manager


app = TestApp()
app.run()
```

Does anyone know what is going on here? Thank you in advance for your help.
Full Error Log :
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/me/Documents/Kivy Project/Table.py", line 57, in 
app = TestApp(self)
NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Which line do you get the error on?

Comment: pls provide full error log

Answer (score 0):

In your `__init__()` method for `SecondScreen` you are providing a key word argument:

```
        orientation = "lr-tb",
```

that is not supported by `MDDataTable`. Just remove that line.

Comment: The thing is that when I remove that I get the following error: ValueError: TableRecycleGridLayout.orientation is set to an invalid option 'vertical'. Must be one of: ['lr-tb', 'tb-lr', 'rl-tb', 'tb-rl', 'lr-bt', 'bt-lr', 'rl-bt', 'bt-rl']

Comment: That is reported as a bug to kivymd [here](https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/issues/912). The suggested fix is: "Use KivyMD library from master branch".